# signtool.exe fails with: "SignerTimeStampEx2() failed." (-2145844844/0x80190194) when signing executable

Tags: windows-10, certificate, code-signing, signtool

I'm using `signtool` to sign an executable on Windows 10, using a GlobalSign certificate. This has worked like a charm for years. Recently it has stopped working. Using the following command line:

```
signtool.exe sign /a /v /n SomeName /tr http://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll some.exe
```

I see that the correct certificate is selected, but then get the following error message:

```
Error information: "SignerTimeStampEx2() failed." (-2145844844/0x80190194)
SignTool Error: An unexpected internal error has occurred.
```

Any idea what it means and how to fix it? The [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccrypto/signtool) unfortunately does not list any error codes.

Comment: the code means **HTTP_E_STATUS_NOT_FOUND**

Comment: Thanks for that hint! I.e. it's a HTTP 404 status for  `http://timestamp.globalsign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll`? And, may I ask how you know that it's a 404?

Comment: maybe your firewall blocks access to it

Comment: I have just encountered exactly the same error. A batch file called from an MSVC project that has been working for years. I did recently change from /t to /tr but it seemed to work after that. Tried again today, and getting this error. Seems to randomly sign some files OK but not others.

Comment: Indeed, Phil, every now and then it seems to work. You might want to upvote the question, so that it gets more attention.

Comment: I thought this might have been a temporary glitch with globalsign, but just tried again today and still have the same problem.

Comment: I wonder if instead of changing /t to /tr I should instead be using a different server url for the timestamp?

Comment: I tried re-issuing the certificate. Made no difference.

Comment: I tried contactnig Globalsign - no reply to my ticket yet.

Comment: I found this article:https://support.globalsign.com/code-signing/code-signing-windows-7-8-and-10 which has a different set of options for signtool.

Comment: The main differences are, not including the cross certificate; using the /td option; and using a different timestamp url. Not sure which of these changes has done the trick, but (touch wood) seems to be working now.

Comment: @PhilPreen Please feel free to post an answer so that I can accept it. I've tried `/td` and the hints from https://support.globalsign.com/code-signing/code-signing-windows-7-8-and-10 and it seems to be working again. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue. I think the Globalsign server may have been upgraded at some point and now needs different parameters for signtool.

See: https://support.globalsign.com/code-signing/code-signing-windows-7-8-and-10

Not sure if all these steps were needed but this worked for me:

1. I re-issued the certificate
2. I changed the timestamp url to: http://rfc3161timestamp.globalsign.com/advanced
3. I added: /td SHA256
4. I removed the reference to the cross certificate

See: https://support.globalsign.com/code-signing/code-signing-windows-7-8-and-10

Comment: This worked for me, even *without* re-issuing the certificate or removing the reference to the cross certificate.

Comment: I re-issued the certificate, as when I visited the Globalsign site there was warning about some certificates needing to be re-issued because of some sort of security issue. It didn't look like this applied, but didn't think it would hurt to try it.
I wonder if I should add the cross certificate back in? If I recall correctly, I think this was no longer needed with the USB token. I never bothered removing it at the time as it didn't seem to cause a problem and would mean updating it in various places.

Comment: Worker for by adding `/td SHA256`, was already using the mentioned timestamp URL.